# How to redirect all AMP ?amp=1 URLs to normal links in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have a problem with amp in wordpress I use the amp plugin and when I delete it google has indexed my website as amp links like https://mywebsite.com?ammp=1

I want to redirect all the visits from  https://mywebsite.com?ammp=1 to https://mywebsite.com
 I see this solution using regex and redirect plugin

```
^/(.*)\/amp
```

but it's only work with this url extension https://mywebsite.com/amp/
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwqQu.png)

```
^/(.*)\/amp
```

I expect it's will work with this https://mywebsite.com?ammp=1

Answer (score 0):

use 301 redirection

```
function redirect_to_specific_page() {
    if(!empty($_GET['amp'])){
            $current_page = get_the_permalink(get_the_ID());
            wp_redirect( $current_page, 301 ); 
            exit;
    }

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page');
```